# Implement ClickHandler in custom Widget

Tags: gwt

I am creating a custom widget in GWT extending Composite and implementing ClickHandler. I have already implemented the method onClick, but the clickEvent does not work. What method should I additionally implement in the class in order the clickEvent to work? May be HandlerRegistration? How?

Comment: Please mark one of those answers as accepted as they probably answered to your question and solved your problem.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want your widget to behave like clickable GWT widgets you should use *com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.HasClickHandlers* interface.

```java
public class MyWidget extends Widget
implements HasClickHandlers
{
    public HandlerRegistration addClickHandler(
        ClickHandler handler)
    {
        return addDomHandler(handler, ClickEvent.getType());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try

```java
this.addClickHandler( myClckHandler ) ;
```

or if not available

```java
this.addDomHandler( myClckHandler , ClickEvent.getType()) ;
```

this should works

edit==>
this should works:

```java
public class Foo extends Composite {

private ClickHandler myClkHandler = new ClickHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        Window.alert("Overnuts is the best !") ;
    }
};

public Foo() {
    initWidget(this) ;
    this.addDomHandler( myClkHandler, ClickEvent.getType()) ;
   }
}
```

Comment: Where? In the constructor? Waht it is then myClickHandler?

Comment: It still does not change anything. I suppose it has to do with HandlerRegistration.